# How to pair the Arf with Stiefel-Whitney class?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

1. The [Arf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arf_invariant) is a nonsingular quadratic form over a field of characteristic 2.

The form that I looked at was:
$$
S(q)=|H^1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)|^{-1/2} \sum_{x\in H^1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)} \exp[\pi \;i\; q(x)]
$$ 
see [Kirby-Taylor, Pin structures on low-dimensional manifolds](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/papers/Kirby%20and%20Taylor%20-%20Pin%20structures%20on%20low-dimensional%20manifolds%20-%20MR1171915.pdf).

The $M^2$ is an oriented 2 dimensional manifold with spin structures that has $\mathbb{Z}_2$ valued quadratic forms on $H_1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, which obeys $$q(x + y) = q(x) +
x ∩ y + q(y) \mod 2,$$ here $x ∩ y$ denotes the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ intersection pairing. The bordism invariant is the Arf invariant.

2. Stiefel-Whitney class is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-characteristic class associated to real vector bundles. For example, we can take the $w_i(TM)$ for the tangent bundle of the base manifold $M$.

> **Question**:
>
> - Is there some precise way to pair the Arf invariant $S(q)$ with Stiefel-Whitney class $w_i(TM)$? How would one write and define them formally as a topological invariant? Like
>     $$
>   S(q) \cup w_{d-2}(TM)?
>   $$
>     where the $M$ is a $d$-dimensional manifold? How do one cup product this two objects formally?
> - Must this $S(q) \cup w_{d-2}(TM)$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-characteristic class?
> - What will be a nontrivial manifold generator $M$ for such an invariant $S(q) \cup w_{d-2}(TM)$?